# soem_core CATKIN_IGNORED? Beckhoff IOs

Tags: ros, orocos, realtime, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to compile this package: git clone https://github.com/orocos/rtt_soem.git (from the tutorials)

It seems soem_core is deprecated. May I know where is the new soem_core?

Better still, how can I utilize Beckhoff IOs using ROS?

Regards,
Walter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253467/soem_core-catkin_ignored?-beckhoff-ios/) by [Walter_SG](https://answers.ros.org/users/29220/walter_sg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schwarzp93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26621/schwarzp93/) on 2018-08-09**:
Hey Guys,

I'm also facing problems with the SOEM-Package. I Want to communicate with Beckhoff IOs via EtherCAT using ROS. Walter, did it work for you?

Thanks in advance, Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deprecated soem_core in favor of the more up to date soem from https://github.com/smits/soem.git adding this to your catkin workspace should make it work (catkin_make_isolated/catkin install as soem is a plane cmake package).  The latest  rtt_soem should work fine with this newer version.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0